# Is it possible to convert GIF file in JPG and save from one place to another in php?

Tags: php, type-conversion, jpeg, gif

Is there any way to convert GIF file in JPG using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to convert image formats in PHP.

One way is with GD:

```
$im=imagecreatefromgif("agifimage.gif");
imagejpeg($im, "ajpegimage.jpg");
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: @dnl Or >= 2.0.28, which is not unreasonably new.

Comment: Dear icktoofay, This code not working. coz i am watermarking this image after conversion. y'know gif doesn't allow alph transparency. Due to this i am converting gif to jpg. Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) libraries or friendly wrappers around them like [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).